# How to get unique selector on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm trying to get unique selector on jQuery. There is two codes with same selector ? How can I choose the second part ??

```js
const data = $('.row table tr').map(function() {
  const a = $(this).find('td:first-child a');
  const td = $(this).find('td:last-child');

  return {
    version: a.text(),
    href: a.attr('href'),
    date: td.text()
  }
}).get();
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
  <table class="striped" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>App Download Version</td><td><span>1.12</span></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Last Updated</td><td><span>April 8, 2018</span></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Apk Size</td><td><span>3.0M</span></td></tr>
      <tr><td>App by</td><td><span>Free Music - </span></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Category</td><td><a title="Download Music &amp; Audio apps apks" href="/category/music-audio/1/"><span>Free</span><span> Music &amp; Audio</span> App</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Content Rating</td><td>Teen</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Support Android Version</td><td><span>Android 15 and above</span></td></tr>
      <tr><td>App Package</td><td class="hide-on-small-only">com.musicstreaming.freemusic</td><td class="hide-on-med-and-up">com.musicstr...</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- Second Part -->

  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
    <table class="striped" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a title="download Free Music 1.12 apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.musicstreaming.freemusic_2018-04-08.apk');" href="/download-app/com.musicstreaming.freemusic/4_com.musicstreaming.freemusic_2018-04-08.apk/">1.12</a></td>
          <td>April 8, 2018</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why won't you use id's?

Comment: What id's ? could u give me a code, please ?

Comment: its an attribute which make that perticular element unique just like a page number in a textbook

Comment: like this `.row table tr [1]` ?

Comment: like `#myUniqueTr` and in the html `<tr id="myUniqueTr"></tr>`

Comment: i can't edit html code, cause it's not my site

Comment: i'm trying to scrap it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either like this:

```js
const data = $($('.row').get(1)).find('table tr').map(function() {
  const a = $(this).find('td:first-child a');
  const td = $(this).find('td:last-child');

  return {
    version: a.text(),
    href: a.attr('href'),
    date: td.text()
  }
}).get();
```

Or like this:

```js
const data = $(document.getElementsByClassName('row')[1]).find('table tr').map(function() {
  const a = $(this).find('td:first-child a');
  const td = $(this).find('td:last-child');

  return {
    version: a.text(),
    href: a.attr('href'),
    date: td.text()
  }
}).get();
```

```js
const data = $($('.row').get(1)).find('table tr').map(function() {
  const a = $(this).find('td:first-child a');
  const td = $(this).find('td:last-child');

  return {
    version: a.text(),
    href: a.attr('href'),
    date: td.text()
  }
}).get();
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
  <table class="striped" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>App Download Version</td>
        <td><span>1.12</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Last Updated</td>
        <td><span>April 8, 2018</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Apk Size</td>
        <td><span>3.0M</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>App by</td>
        <td><span>Free Music - </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td><a title="Download Music &amp; Audio apps apks" href="/category/music-audio/1/"><span>Free</span><span> Music &amp; Audio</span> App</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content Rating</td>
        <td>Teen</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Support Android Version</td>
        <td><span>Android 15 and above</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>App Package</td>
        <td class="hide-on-small-only">com.musicstreaming.freemusic</td>
        <td class="hide-on-med-and-up">com.musicstr...</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- Second Part -->

  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
    <table class="striped" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a title="download Free Music 1.12 apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.musicstreaming.freemusic_2018-04-08.apk');" href="/download-app/com.musicstreaming.freemusic/4_com.musicstreaming.freemusic_2018-04-08.apk/">1.12</a></td>
          <td>April 8, 2018</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**EDIT**

Instead of this:

```js
$($('.row').get(1)).find('table tr')...
```

It is use `eq()` function

```js
$('.row').eq(1).find('table tr')...
```

```js
const data = $('.row').eq(1).find('table tr').map(function() {
  const a = $(this).find('td:first-child a');
  const td = $(this).find('td:last-child');

  return {
    version: a.text(),
    href: a.attr('href'),
    date: td.text()
  }
}).get();
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
  <table class="striped" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>App Download Version</td>
        <td><span>1.12</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Last Updated</td>
        <td><span>April 8, 2018</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Apk Size</td>
        <td><span>3.0M</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>App by</td>
        <td><span>Free Music - </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td><a title="Download Music &amp; Audio apps apks" href="/category/music-audio/1/"><span>Free</span><span> Music &amp; Audio</span> App</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content Rating</td>
        <td>Teen</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Support Android Version</td>
        <td><span>Android 15 and above</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>App Package</td>
        <td class="hide-on-small-only">com.musicstreaming.freemusic</td>
        <td class="hide-on-med-and-up">com.musicstr...</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- Second Part -->

  <div class="row" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
    <table class="striped" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a title="download Free Music 1.12 apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.musicstreaming.freemusic_2018-04-08.apk');" href="/download-app/com.musicstreaming.freemusic/4_com.musicstreaming.freemusic_2018-04-08.apk/">1.12</a></td>
          <td>April 8, 2018</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can i choose two selectors div, like ('.row').get(1).get(2)?

Comment: @НекТраммм I'm not sure about `get()` but you can do it wit `eq()` like `$('.row').eq(1, 2)`. This what you suggested would not work because `$('.row').get(1)` returns only second element, so you can't get third element from second one :)

Comment: yes you're right eq(1, 2) works ) Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You can go with

```
const data = $('.row:eq(1) table tr').map(function() {
     const a = $(this).find('td:first-child a');
     const td = $(this).find('td:last-child');

     return {
       version: a.text(),
       href: a.attr('href'),
       date: td.text()
     }
   }).get();
```

Comment: i'm trying this method but unfortunately it gives me `SyntaxError: unmatched pseudo-class :eq` in html code this site have 12 row div, so i choose 8 and it dont work ( HTML code [link](https://www.apkmonk.com/app/com.musicstreaming.freemusic/), maybe you could look at this html code, and help me ?

Comment: Don't know why it wouldn't work though, maybe something conflicting with Jquery in your code. Check js fiddle here (same jquery version as yours) : https://jsfiddle.net/btpcx021/1/

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$('.row table tr')
```

with

```
$('.row').eq(1).find('table tr')
```

[jquery .eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)